# Dotnet Runtime 8.0.0 not found in Ubuntu 23.10 arm64

Tags: asp.net, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, asp.net-core-webapi

I am doing a project with Ubuntu 23.10 in a Raspberry Pi 5.

Using Docker, I created this image with the netcore runtime files dowloaded from:

https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/91223e4e-2300-4e8e-9364-09ea1c317294/47fb26a2df5eeee08f77a4d1b720a34a/aspnetcore-runtime-8.0.0-linux-arm64.tar.gz

```
FROM alpine:3.19

USER root

ENV DLL_NAME=application
EXPOSE 443

WORKDIR /application
VOLUME /application

COPY ./aspnetcore-runtime-8.0.0-linux-arm64 /dotnet_runtime

RUN chmod +x /dotnet_runtime/dotnet

RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps openssl icu tzdata && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

WORKDIR /dotnet_runtime

CMD ./dotnet /application/${DLL_NAME}.dll --urls "https://*"
```

In the Docker Compose file I have:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  API:
    container_name: 'my_container'
    image: my_image/dotnet_runtime:8.0.0
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - database
    ports:
      - '443:443'
    environment:
      TZ: 'Europe/Madrid'
      DLL_NAME: MY_DLL
    mem_limit: 1GB
    volumes:
      - '/server_data/docker_volumes/API:/application'
```

When I execute docker-compose up -d to create the container I recieve the following error:

```
/bin/sh: ./dotnet: not found
/bin/sh: ./dotnet: not found
/bin/sh: ./dotnet: not found
/bin/sh: ./dotnet: not found
/bin/sh: ./dotnet: not found
/bin/sh: ./dotnet: not found
/bin/sh: ./dotnet: not found
```

I have tried with the full SDK too and it's the same. Can someone explain what's wrong with this? Thank you!

Comment: 1) there prebuild docker alpine images with .NET installed you can use them 2) if you don't want too - then install the runtime [via package manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-alpine#install-the-runtime) - `sudo apk add dotnet8-runtime` 3) if this is still is not an option for some reason - consider [scripted install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#scripted-install) 4) if you still want to install it manually- read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#manual-install)

Comment: It's also possible this is the symptom of the image not containing a C shared library you need.  This can be a place where a Debian- or Ubuntu-based image is more likely to work unmodified, or you might need to install some additional library packages.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks! But same result trying this..

Comment: @GuruStron Thank you for the answer! I tried all the options and I still get the same error

Comment: I got a similar problem and found out that in my case I have to use "Place solution and project in the same directory" options checked in visual studio.

Comment: Why don't you use `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-alpine`?

Comment: Very similar as the comment above, I would use `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-alpine AS final`

Answer (score 0):

So I too experienced that managing runtimes can be a pain in Docker. I wouldn't download the runtime over a URL because that's a step that you have to do manually and the point of docker is that you build and run the container and don't worry about the dependencies. Here I have created a Dockerfile that first restores your projects that it builds them, and then it runs them with the right runtime. And Docker will handle that the right packages for the right architecture are downloaded, and you don't have to manually download any runtimes anymore. I have changed your configuration a little bit how I would write it, but you are still free to change things up later. I hope this helps!

```
FROM alpine:3.19

USER root
ENV DLL_NAME=application

# Here you first download the sdk and build the app
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /source

# Just copy the csproj to run dotnet restore
COPY *.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

# Now you can copy the resot of the files and build the app
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o /application --no-restore

# Create your certificate
RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps openssl icu tzdata && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

# Download the image for the runtime
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-alpine AS final

# Set the workdir to the directory where the dll is compiled
WORKDIR /application

# Expose ports and mount your volumes
EXPOSE 443
VOLUME /application

# Instead of passing an argument you can set ENV variables
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+"

# Use the entrypoint where every argument is in a list
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "${DLL_NAME}.dll"]
```